# Find and replace with an instance of a word in vim

Tags: vim

What I'm trying to do is find an instance of a piece of code e.g.

```
<textarea id="question1">
```

and replace it with a part of itself:

```
<textarea id="question1" name="question1">
```

How can I reference "question1" in :%s of vim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
:%s;<textarea id="\([^"]*\)">;<textarea id="\1" name="\1">;
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Just out of curiosity, what do the semicolons do?

Comment: @bswinnerton: it is a command separator. you can choose any character as separator. e.g. `:`